# How to write PHP if statement inside PHP string element?

Tags: php, html

```
$element = " <div class='product-info'>
                <p>$Name</p>
                <?php if () {}?>
                <p>$Title</p>
            </div>";
```

this variable $element contains HTML code and I want to run this if statement inside of it but without splitting the variable because I want to echo this whole variable somewhere else.

Comment: Don't put if statements inside of your strings. Put strings inside of your if statements.

Comment: _I want to echo this whole variable somewhere else_ OK you can do that even by _splitting the variable_.

Comment: Ok, I inserted the string inside the if statement, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you're asking, but you can do something that has the same effect:

```
$element = " <div class='product-info'><p>$Name</p>";

 if (some condition) {
      $element .= "some text";
 } Else {
      $element .= "Some other text";
 }
 $element .= "<p>$Title</p> </div>";
```

Comment: In other words, "put strings inside your if statements"